# Teams bot Activity.CreateReply throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a bot for Microsoft Teams. I am using the custom bot feature. I got the bot working as a sideloaded package, but due to the constraints of my network, I need to keep the bot internal and use the custom bot feature. I am currently testing it by using ngrok to tunnel to my localhost.

I am now running into an issue when I try to create my reply. Whenever I call this:

```
var reply = activity.CreateReply(message.ReadToEnd());
```

I get a NullReferenceException saying that the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". message is an open .txt file. I get this error every time I call activity.CreateReply(). The part that I don't understand is that everything works as intended in the Bot Framework Emulator and when the bot is a sideloaded package, but not when the bot is a custom bot.

Here's my full Post method:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            // Commands:
            // Retrieve TFS Work Item(s)
            if (new Regex(@"\but\s?\d{5}\b").IsMatch(activity.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                var reply = new RetrieveWorkItem();
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply.Response(activity));
            }
            // Help
            else if (activity.Text.ToLower().Contains("help"))
            {
                var message = File.OpenText($"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}/Messages/HelpMessage.txt");
                var reply = activity.CreateReply(message.ReadToEnd());
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
            }
            // Not Recognized
            else
            {
                var reply = activity.CreateReply("Command not recognized. Type \"@Keller Bot Help\" for a list of commands.");
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity, connector);
        }

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Here's the full error and StackTrace sent by the bot: https://pastebin.com/ZSrjrA9z

Comment: are you sure that the file is being opened ok?

Comment: Yes, the issue is not with the file because it opens just fine when the bot is sideloaded or being ran from the emulator using the exact same callback URL. I didn't mean to call much attention attention to message, as all of my activity.CreateReply() calls throw the same exception, including the one under // Not Recognized that takes in a simple string.

Comment: is anyone able to reproduce this?  I tried and I cannot

Comment: What do you have into your `reply`  object ?

Comment: It is either a message containing only a string, or a message with some thumbnail cards attached to it. Neither work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you're implementing this as a custom bot, per the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/custombot).  The issue is that it appears as if you're using the Bot Framework messaging calls (e.g. CreateReply()), which won't work since you're not dealing with a registered BF bot when you go through the custom bot process.

Instead, you can just create a new Activity() and return that in response to the HttpPost request.

We do have a [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-custombot) you can check out, in case that helps.

Comment: That works, thank you. I have a further question about the limitations of a custom bot. The documentation says that the custom bot cannot leverage button actions such as "imBack and "invoke". Does this mean that buttons cannot do anything more than open a URL?